# How to make thrift 0.8 build go library?

Tags: go, thrift

I download thrift 0.8 tarball,and my GOROOT is "/home/alex/go",what should be modified to make sure go library got built when compile thrift?

Currently,when run ./configure got

```
.......
Building PHP Library ......... : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : yes
Building Go Library .......... : no     (is this saying go library won't be built?)
```

Comment: Try to change GOROOT to another path. For example go binary located here: /usr/bin/go, so GOROOT path will looks like: GOROOT=/usr

Answer (score 1):

thrift do not support Go 1 yet. The configure script try to find the old go commands to build go library.

```
configure:19244: checking for 6g
configure:19274: result: /home/jarod/dev/go/go-hg/bin//6g
configure:19284: checking for 6l
configure:19314: result: /home/jarod/dev/go/go-hg/bin//6l
configure:19324: checking for gomake
configure:19354: result: /home/jarod/dev/go/go-hg/bin//gomake
configure:19364: checking for goinstall
configure:19394: result: /home/jarod/dev/go/go-hg/bin//goinstall
```

Comment: according the description of here:https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go/pull/15,thrift4go's creator has updated source to support GO-1,but has not been integrated into thrift trunk,I should do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run `./configure --help` and look for something like `--enable-go` or `--with-go` command line options — it may well happen that building of the Go library is just not attempted *by default.* I have never tried to build thrift myself so I have no idea about whether it's true or not; check yourself.

If you're sure building of the Go library is enabled by default, you'll have to check why `configure` was not satisfied with your environment.  Look at the `config.log` file produced by the `./configure` run and search for the "Building go Library" substring in there — somewhere around its occurence, you'll find what test the `configure` script performed, and why it failed.

If the cause is still unclear after investigation, look at the `configure` script code — it's just a shell script after all (complex but still readable for a programmer).